# Show Custom Dialog on clicking RecyclerView cart icon

Tags: android

I have created a RecyclerView showing list of songs coming from server. Now I want to show a dialog to the user whenever user clicks on the cart icon. For reference I have uploaded and image.
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use PopupMenu.
see this example [enter link description here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)